# How to check in application document folder whether this files is or not in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have app in which i have recorded sound files i want that i may check that if files which i need or existing it should upload to server other wise not

I have type array in which there values like vital etc i want that if this file exits i have method like [self upload] then that it should be called otherwise not

```
    int i=0;
    for (i=0; i<[types count]; i++) {


    NSString*type=[types objectAtIndex:i];

   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 




   NSString * filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@_%@_%@_%@.wav", NSHomeDirectory(),theCellData.firstName,theCellData.lasttName,theCellData.patientId,type];




  BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];

   }
```

Comment: What is the problem ? As you are checking file exists or not.

Comment: it not showing any thing in BOOL

Comment: did you try putting breakpoint there ? or put NSLog(@"%d",fileExists); This will print either 0 or 1 if 1 than exists if 0 than not.

Comment: I am NSLog(fileExists) it crashes

Comment: Did you try copy paste my code ? Add your code how do you nslog

Comment: Use this, it might help.


  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638834/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-documents-folder

Comment: Jani :try logging like this : NSLog(@"%d",fileExists); . As fileExists is a bool variable NSLog(fileExists) will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i=0;
for (i=0; i<[types count]; i++) 
{
NSString*type=[types objectAtIndex:i];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@_%@_%@_%@.wav",documentsDirectory,theCellData.firstName,theCellData.lasttName,theCellData.patientId,type];
 BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
if (fileExists == 0) 
{
    NSLog(@"File is Not exists");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"File exists");
 }
}
```

Comment: i am accepting your code but can you edit my code and give that path in your code

Answer (score 0):

Much like the answer above, but for completeness, what your code should look like, based on your question.  (I'm guessing you're somewhat new to Cocoa...)

```
NSString* documentsPath1 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* foofile = [documentsPath1 stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@_%@_%@_%@.wav", theCellData.firstName, theCellData.lasttName, theCellData.patientId, type];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: foofile];
if (fileExists == NO) 
{
     NSLog(@"File does not exist");
}
else
{
     NSLog(@"File exists");
}
```