# Check file exists in a folder inside Directory in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsbundle, file-exists, nsdocumentdirectory

I am new to iPhone,

I want to check whether `Myfile` exists in folder inside `DocumentDirectory` ?

**For eg:**

`Myfile.epub` is one of my file and i want to check whether this file exists at my `DestPath` or not ?

`DestPath` is my `DocumentDirectory` path.

```
DestPath=/Users/krunal/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/D414BC19-C005-4D93-896D-A6FB71DE4D21/Documents/Derivatives
```

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a file exists in Documents folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638834/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-documents-folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution worked for me..
 You don't want to give the entire part of your path like **/Users/krunal/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/D414BC19-C005-4D93-896D-A6FB71DE4D21/Documents/Derivatives**

you have to give **Derivatives/Myfile.epub (FolderName/filename)**  for checking the file path

```
    NSFileManager *filemanager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];  

    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory= [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Derivatives/Myfile.epub"];

    BOOL success =[filemanager fileExistsAtPath:path];

    if (success == YES) {   

        NSLog(@"exists");
    }
    else {

       NSLog(@"not exists");

    }
```

Comment: check my `DestPath` there is a folder inside Document folder i want to check `Myfile.epub` is present inside `DestPath` or not.

Comment: you have to give FolderName/Myfile.epub for checking the file path

Answer (score 2):

you also can try..

```
NSString *path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file"];
success=[filemanager fileExistsAtPath:path];
```

Comment: check my `DestPath` there is a folder inside Document folder i want to check `Myfile.epub` is present inside `DestPath` or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Get the Document directory path 

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
 NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
 documentsPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Myfile.epub"];
 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsPath]) 
 {
    //file not exits in Document Directories
 }
  else
  {
    //file exist in Document Directories
  }
```