# set an Image for a UIbutton from documents directory

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to set an image for a UIButton from documents directory

i tried this:

```
-(IBAction) vignettesBank1:(id)sender {

NSString *localPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

NSString *imageBouton1 = [localPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"btn01.png"]];

[boutonVideo1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageBouton1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSLog(@"imageBouton1=%@",imageBouton1);}
```

**log return :
imageBouton1=/var/mobile/Applications/164F9A40-10AF-402E-A46C-73084CAA8627/Documents/btn01.png**

i try this too :

```
-(IBAction) vignettesBank1:(id)sender {

NSArray  *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDir  = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString  *pngfile = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"btn01.png"];

[boutonVideo1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:pngfile] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

NSLog(@"imageBouton1=%@",pngfile);}
```

**log return the same :
imageBouton1=/var/mobile/Applications/164F9A40-10AF-402E-A46C-73084CAA8627/Documents/btn01.png**

my button doesn't load my image
thank's for your help

Comment: have you checked if the path it's the same as the path were the image was saved? the image extension is correct?

Comment: yes i checked the path is correct and i open my app with ifunbox and my image is in the Documents directory -:((

Comment: then, you can try with `NSFileManager` as `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:pngfile]`, it returns a `NSData` so then you can init an `UIImage` with this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imageNamed: is for files in you bundle. You should use

```
NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: imageBouton1]];
[boutonVideo1 setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:pngfile] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: sorry, i just updated my answer, should be [NSURL fileURLWithPath: imageBouton1]

Comment: @ dminones      still not work with :    `NSString *localPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
        
    NSString *imageBouton1 = [localPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"btn01.png"]];
    NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: imageBouton1]];
    [boutonVideo1 setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: did you confirm that this image exists at that path?

Comment: yes i open my app with ifunbox and my file is inside my Documents directory (i puted it with itunes in the shared file directory of my app)

Comment: you could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638834/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-documents-folder to see if this is true from your app perspective, i would debug this issue with the simulator where is easier see your devices files

Comment: works fine with -->  setBackgroundImage  --- stange ---

Comment: is the button type custom? frame with the right size?

Comment: you should try with button type custom

Comment: work's fine with type :custom !!! YES!  thank's a lot my friend  ....  +1 for you